# Replacing a value with its previous value in a column if it is greater

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [101, 90, 11, 120, 1]
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `y`:

```
     a    y
0  101    101.0
1   90    101.0
2   11    90.0
3  120    120.0
4    1    120.0
```

Basically, values in `a` are compared with their previous value, and the greater one is selected.

For example for row `1`, 90 is compared with 101. 101 is greater so it is selected.

I have done it in this way:

```
df['x'] = df.a.shift(1)
df['y'] = df[['a', 'x']].max(axis=1)
```

Is there a cleaner or some kind of built-in way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.fmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html#numpy.fmax) to get the maxima without creating an additional column:

```py
df["y"] = np.fmax(df["a"], df["a"].shift(1))
```

This outputs:

```py
     a      y
0  101  101.0
1   90  101.0
2   11   90.0
3  120  120.0
4    1  120.0
```

We use `np.fmax()` to ignore the `NaN` created when shifting `df["a"]`.

Comment: Thanks. Is that `dataframe` tag a new trend? :) Maybe I must use it for my future posts

Comment: I've noticed it on quite a few `pandas` questions for awhile. I mostly add it for completeness, it can't hurt since the question is about DataFrames. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.assign(y = df['a'].rolling(2,min_periods=1).max())
```

Output:

```
     a      y
0  101  101.0
1   90  101.0
2   11   90.0
3  120  120.0
4    1  120.0
```