# Keep the previous maximum value and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1, 9, 8, 10, 7, 11, 20]
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `b`:

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   9   9
2   8   9
3  10  10
4   7  10
5  11  11
6  20  20
```

This is actually a problem when I am converting code from Pine Script to Python. I am not used to thinking in this way.

I explain the issue with an example:

Row `0` in `b` is always `df.a.iloc[0]`. Now in order to get the next row in `b`, row number `1` in `a` should be compared with row number `0` in `b`. The greater one is selected for `b`. In this case 9 > 1 so 9 is selected.

For next row in `b` row number `2` in `a` is compared with row number `1` in `b`. 9 > 8 so 9 is selected. And it goes to the end. This image clarifies the issue:

[image]

I tried a lot of solutions. But, since I am not used to this kind of logic, It feels like I'm running in circles. This is one of my attempts:

```
df["b"] = np.fmax(df["a"], df["a"].shift(1))
```

Comment: This is exactly the same question as you just asked and it has the same solution, `df['b'] = df['a'].cummax()`

Comment: Or am I missing something? If so, please [edit] your question to make it clear what is different, and I will re-open. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.cummax()`:

```py
df["b"] = df["a"].cummax()
```

This outputs:

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   9   9
2   8   9
3  10  10
4   7  10
5  11  11
6  20  20
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions (especially ones which have just been asked by the same user). You should be using your gold badge to close them instead.

Comment: Huh, I thought it was a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77740923/17769815) question which I answered. My answer, which was accepted, is the same as attempt provided in this question.

Comment: I hadn't seen that one. But OP just asked exactly the same question which I guess you missed an hour earlier.